# How to upload a new revision / version to an existing word document in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

How to upload a new revision / version to an existing Word document in Google Docs. I am able to see an "Import a new version" for a spreadsheet (`xlsx`) but not for a Word file (docx). Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official way to do this as far as I know.
But you could upload the document as a new file and copy paste from it to the old file.
This way you even get to keep the revision history.

Comment: While this works, the revision history will show the previous version is entirely deleted and the new version written entirely from scratch.  There's no way to tell what's changed between revisions.  It doesn't show up as changing one word or adding a new paragraph, as it would if the document had been edited.